# Show value of custom category description to single post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to pull out the description value of the custom category i have created using jetengine (similar to ACF). unfortunately, jetengine doesnt have the option to do this that why i have created my custom shortcode

```
/* function for programs category description */
  function custom_desc_func() {
  ob_start();
  $terms = get_terms(
  array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'program-episode',
    'hide_empty' => false,
   )
   );
   if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $tid = $term->term_id;
   }
    ?>
        <span>
            <?php echo get_term_meta(46, 'program-intro-description', true 
     ) ?>
        </span>
    <?php

     }
    return ob_get_clean();
     }
    add_shortcode('custom_desc', 'custom_desc_func');
```

/* end of function for programs category description */

The code is working but as you can see, im manually adding category id number in the code (46) - how do i make this more dynamic?

e.g

1. ''Post A and Post B'' has ''Cat A'' assigned in them....then I want the custom description of ''Cat A ''to appear on both posts (A & B) on the front end

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code and let me know.

```
function custom_desc_func() {
ob_start();
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'program-episode');
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 $tid = $term->term_id;
}
?>
<span>
<?php echo get_term_meta($tid, 'program-intro-description', true); ?>
</span>
<?php
}
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom_desc', 'custom_desc_func');
```

Comment: hi, it does the same thing, we still have the 46 in there meaning it will only show the description of that category on all posts. e.g POST B has CAT B - then POST B will show CAT B description.. so on and so fort

Comment: got it working! thanks for the hints  <?php echo get_term_meta($tid, 'program-intro-description', true); ?>